# How to unit test method where you cannot inject dependency

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I have the following code:

```
class Plugin {

    protected $manager;

    public function activate(Composer $composer, IOInterface $io)
    {
        $this->manager = new Manager();
        $this->doSomething($this->manager);
     }

    private function doSomething(Managaer $manager)
    {
        $manager->add('first', function() {
            //do something.
        });

        $manager->add('second', function() {
           //do something.
        });
    }
}
```

How can I assert that the `add` method was called on the `Manager` class?

The `Plugin` class is instantiated for me and cannot have dependencies injected. The activate method is also called for me (not in my control), so I cannot pass in dependencies.

I usually test this by having the following extra method and mocking it to return a mocked instance of `Manager`

```
class Plugin {

    protected $manager;

    public function activate(Composer $composer, IOInterface $io)
    {
        $this->doSomething($this->getManager());
    }

    private function doSomething(Manager $manager)
    {
        $manager->add('first', function() {
            //do something.
        });

        $manager->add('second', function() {
           //do something.
        });
    }

    public function getManager()
    {
        return new Manager;
    }
}
```

And that would look like the following:

```
//get a mock manager
$manager = $this->getMock('Manager');

//assert that method should be called
$manager->expects($this->once())
    ->method('add')
    ->with($this->isInstanceOf('Closure'));

//create mock plugin but only mock getManager method
$plugin = $this->getMock('Plugin');
$plugin->expects($this->once())
    ->method('getManager')
    ->will($this->returnValue($manager));

$plugin->activate(/** args **/);
```

This to me, feel hacky. I don't feel like I should be mocking the `Plugin` class. How do other people tackle this issue?

Do you have a setter & a getter for the Manager? where if a class variable is not set, return a default instance. This way in the tests I can call the `setManager()` method with a mocked instance?

That also doesn't sound great because I'm writing extra code just to unit test the class!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to modify the `Plugin` class you have under test directly, just create yourself some way to inject your manager mock into it:

```
class PluginTester extends Plugin
{
  public function setManager(Plugin $plugin, Manager $manager) {
    $plugin->manager = $manager;
  }
}
```

You can then use it to inject the mock:

```
$plugin = new Plugin();
$stubManager = new ManagerMock();

$util = new PluginTester();
$util->setManager($plugin, $stubManager);
```

Alternatively do not use the `new` keyword inside or your class if you really need to mock those objects. It's either a private detail - then you don't need to unit test it - or it's not, then you should have it as an dependency or it should be even part of the public interface if it's public.

Comment: Thanks, normally I would inject it, but in this system, the calling code instantiates and calls the methods, therefore I can't inject it. I guess I'm trying to write a test for regression purposes. So it is an internal detail but the tests should assert it still does what it did when it was written. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Well with that little code I don't want to judge if you're doing something wrong or not. Technically the private method `doSomething` won't need the `$manager` parameter as you have it with `$this` already. That actually stands in the way for what I suggest in the answer. Better look what works for you and the do so, that sound not wrong to me :)

Comment: Ok cool, Well this is the actual [test](https://github.com/magento-hackathon/magento-composer-installer/blob/master/tests/MagentoHackathon/Composer/Magento/PluginTest.php#L52) and respective [function](https://github.com/magento-hackathon/magento-composer-installer/blob/master/tests/MagentoHackathon/Composer/Magento/PluginTest.php#L52) where `$this->getEventManager()` was originally just `new EventManager`. I mean, it works, just doesn't feel right.